# Globally-installed NodeJS npm module does not execute the main/bin JavaScript file with node

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, npm

I've a `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "name": "some-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "bin": "./bin/some-module.js",
  "main": "./bin/some-module.js",
  "description": "Some module description",
  "homepage": "http://my.home.page.com",
  "author": {
    "name": "Matias Fidemraizer",
    "email": "no-email@no-email.com",
    "url": "http://some.url.com"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.4.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
     "somekeyword"
  ],
  "license": {
    "type": "Apache v2",
    "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
  },
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/some/repo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
     "somedependency": "*"
  }
}
```

When I try to install the whole module typing `npm -g install /path/to/module/folder`, **npm** creates a `.cmd` file on *AppData* folder in the default `node_modules` location for global installations as expected.

But generated code doesn't include `node.exe` or `node`:

```
"%~dp0\node_modules\some-module\bin\some-module.js"   %*
```

... so when I try to execute my `some-module` module in CMD, PowerShell or whatever, it's executed using Windows Script Host (WSH).

For that reason I thought comparing `package.json` of some existing module like YUIDocJS would be enough to find out what's causing this problem but I can't figure out what's wrong in my own `package.json` so it doesn't create the expected global installation.

Thank you in advance for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the top of the file referenced in the `bin` property of your `package.json`? Even though the shebang is a *nix specific directive, `npm` [depends on its presence to create the shim for the `.cmd`](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/cmd-shim/blob/master/index.js#L22)

Comment: BTW, YuiDocJs package.json lacks this *nix reference!

Comment: Just to be clear: The shebang goes in the bin file, not the package.json... that is why YUIDocJS package.json doesn't have it

Comment: Yeah yeah, big mistake, sorry :)

Comment: You're right! This is the solution. Thank you, it worked! I was looking for diffs comparing `package.json` but I forgot to check the whole bin file.....!!

Comment: Its not well documented... I feel like it deserves a ticket on the [github repo](https://github.com/isaacs/npm) if you have the time =)